# Pysaprk use groupBy() with colRegex

Tags: pyspark, group-by

i try to combine groupBy() with colRegex
So i want automaticly group all Columns with surfix "B_" and last column "Prio" aggregate with max.

But however i try it it doesn't works.

```
df_calc_new = df_calc_new.groupBy((sf.col(colRegex('`B_.*`')) for x in [*df_calc_values_p1.columns])).agg(max(col("Prio")))
```

Comment: what error do you have ? can you add the schema of your dataframe ? some input data sample, and expected output ? What is `sf` ? can you add your imports ?

Comment: if you do that simply in python : `c.startswith("B_") for c in df_calc_values_p1.columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do that in pure python :

```py
c.startswith("B_") for c in df_calc_values_p1.columns
```